# Highcharts. Specifiec label

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart drawed with a highcharts, and I need to create some label inside of the biggest part of a pie But it should be separated from `dataLabels`, so the dataLabels are shown outside but this one label is shown inside of the pie.

I wanna place `my custom label` inside of a green part. I can position it absolutely but I need to get the coordinates of green point. Now I have

```
labels: {
                    items: [{                           
                        html: "My custom label",
                        style: {
                            left: "100px"/*chart.series.data[0].x*/ /*this doesn't work*/,
                            top: "100px"
                        }

                    }]
                },
```

[image: pie_chart]

thanks for any help

Comment: It will be always first slice, or you mark by any option to print there custom label ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by returning two `divs` and moving second to the position I need.